# compilation error java hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

When I execute this class, I have some problems, I don't know what is the solution.

```
package nab;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
public class Test {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    Text a = new Text("aaa");
      System.out.println(a);
    }
  }
}
```

I obtain these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.Text.<clinit>(Text.java:49)
    at nab.Test.main(Test.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Can you explain me what I can do to resolve this problem!

Thank you

Comment: is this org.apache.hadoop.io.Text in the class path?

Comment: I put a hadoop-core.. .jar in referenced librairies .